# Force download file php after has been saved in directory?

Tags: php, mysql, csv, download, vps

Im creating a large mysql database which has business numbers of companies.
I have finaly been able to create the code which allows to save results as csv in a specific directory called "/uploads". everything works fine. Now i need to have a button that downloads file the file after query&save the csv file.

the code is this:

```
 <?php
include 'includes/connection.php';

if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
$cap = $_POST ['cap'];
$prov = $_POST ['provincia'];
$citta = $_POST ['citta'];


$filename = 'uploads/'.strtotime ("now").'.csv';

$sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM business_total  WHERE cap LIKE'%$cap%' AND provincia LIKE '%$prov%' AND citta LIKE '%$citta%'") or die(mysql_error());
$num_rows = mysql_num_rows($sql);
echo 'totale risultato: '.'<b>'.$num_rows.'</b>'.'<br/>';
if($num_rows >= 1)
{

$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql);
$fp = fopen($filename,"w"); 

$seperator = "";
$comma = "";

//$name è la prima righa, quella dei valori
foreach($row as $name => $value)
{
    $seperator.= $comma.''.str_replace('','""',$name);
    $comma =",";

}
$seperator .="\n";

fputs($fp,$seperator);
mysql_data_seek($sql, 0);

//Primo row per le testate, questo row per il contenuto query

while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql))
{

$seperator = "";
$comma = "";

//$name è la prima righa, quella dei valori
foreach($row as $name => $value)
{
    $seperator.= $comma.''.str_replace('','""',$value);
    $comma =",";

}
$seperator .="\n";


fputs($fp,$seperator);
}
fclose($fp);




}
else
{
echo 'Non ci sono risultati compatibili con la tua ricerca';
}




}



?>

 <HTML>
  <head>


 </head>

 <body>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <form method="post" action="index.php">


 <input type="text" name="cap" placeholder="Cerca per cap"/><br>
  <input type="text" name="provincia" placeholder="Cerca per prov"/><br>
  <input type="text" name="citta" placeholder="Cerca per citta"/><br>
   <input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit"/>



 </form>






  </body>


   </HTML>
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem.
added this piece before th php close tag (?>)
here is the code:

```
                        $qfile = $filename;


                        echo $qfile;



                if (file_exists($qfile)) {
                    header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
                    header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
                    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='.basename($qfile));
                    header('Expires: 0');
                    header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate');
                    header('Pragma: public');
                    header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($qfile));
                    readfile($qfile);
                    exit;
    }







 ?>
```